# Edit JPG via WebDav

Tags: java, windows, web, webdav, intranet

We have webdav server, from which we can open for edit office documents (word, excel,...).
But also we need ability to open image (jpg, png) and pdf from this server for editing on client computer (in default app for this computer - like acdsee for jpg and adobe reader for pdf), and we have't clean solution for this task.

Our ideas:

- edit Win registry on client (this is intranet project): add url like "ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|" for openning file on local computer. All what I can find:

"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\ms-word"

but what to do with it, it is not clear.

- Write our own java applet for client side (applet will manage all operations like downloading, opening, blocking files on server, etc). It's clear (more or less) but hard and time-consuming way, I think.

Can anyone give any feedback about this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is mapping a WebDAV resource as network drive or WebFolder is out of the question? It even  could be done via GPO seamlessly.

Relevant question: [How do I get WebDAV working?](https://serverfault.com/questions/402767/how-do-i-get-webdav-working)

Comment: If WebDAV is mapped via network drive, users should be able to view\edit documents. I just checked it myself using our intranet SharePoint portal. I've been able to open picture in my default app (FastStone), resize it and save with the new name to the SharePoint. Could you elaborate, why this doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thank you for response. At now we are going to same solution, as you wrote, with Java applet. Architecture: Our Web portal (java backend and angular on front) will load specifically designed java applet (security signed) to client, and next this applet will communicate with local system (get list of file in specific folder, open .docx file in word, jpg in acdsee, etc).